# SQL Server 2008 and SP1

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

I have a server where I installed SQL Server 2008 and after I applied the SP1.
Now, I want also to add the Analysis Services to this instance by using the "Add or remove features...".

My questions are:

- Is it possible to add the Analysis Services on a server with SP1 already installed?
- How can I apply the SP1 also to the new Analysis Service feature?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add SSAS

Just re-run SP1 (although IIRC the installer is clever enough to do this anyway): you have the option to upgrade instance by instance (and SSAS is a separate instance to the DB engine)

Comment: Is it the same also for the SSRS? Thanks